# How can you send data to another process (at the c++ language level only)

Tags: c++, ipc, c++17

Suppose you are developing two application (A and B).

How can you send some piece of information to B from A **if you are only allowed to work at the c++ language level** (that is including the standard libraries and STL) ?

Now Im thinking std::ofstream and std::ifstream could be a possible solution (albeit a crude one) ?  - but what pitfalls is there and can they be avoided ? (how?).

Comment: Use a file to write/read from either processes?

Comment: You can of course use pipes for the communication. And yes, there's a lot of pitfalls you might meet doing so. Your question is too broad.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i suppose you could link to an example perhaps ?

Comment: @darune [There are many](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+use+stdin+and+stdout+for+ipc+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj12dOc3_zhAhUOKewKHa2ODHgQrQIoBDABegQIBhAL&biw=1600&bih=789)

Comment: Cant you just use sockets? The easiest solution I see is just to write to and read from file.

Comment: To add up upon @styphNate's proposal ZMQ sockets would be a neat way to do so. You'll have maximum control about their behavior.

Comment: stdin/stdout is possible - but how is that for example setup with win32

Comment: @darune You just use the operating system functions to setup a pipe between those  processes. You should note that standard c++ doesn't have any notion about IPC at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ before writing this question, i couldn't find a simpel way to do that (on windows) - can you provide an example ?

Comment: @darune No wonder, there isn't a _"simple way"_. And no, I can't provide a simple example. There are whole books written about that stuff.

Comment: By setting those requirements, you are creating the very problem you now need to solve. The correct way is to either use the system APIs to setup a TCP connection (portable, allow splitting across machine, simple enough) or a shared memory block (more complex, best performance). Iostreams could work, but it's inelegant, and needlessly heavy performance wise. And you still need system stuff to pipe to/from your processes

Comment: With the recent edit, **the meaning of the question changed *completely***. Before the edit, it was about any OS, now it is only about one particular one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just cannot. Standard C++17 does not know about any kind of inter-process communication and does not know much about processes (except thru [`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) whose behavior is not really specified). Some [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) don't have any processes and some of them don't have files and some of them don't have pipes.

Read more about operating systems. I strongly recommend [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (which is freely available).

Of course, you can read and write a file, but the synchronization between the two processes should still happen (perhaps by *running* one after the other, in some operating system specific way, so running A then B, and how that exactly happens is OS specific)

Read that C++17 standard (e.g. the draft [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170325025026/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4660.pdf)) to check.

Some C++17 implementations might not even have any notion of process. You could have a fully compliant C++17 on some embedded system without any operating system dealing with processes.

My recommendation is to **be pragmatical, and use some framework like [Boost](https://boost.org/), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/), or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) (or old [Berkeley sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)) which deals with processes and inter-process communication facilities**; you'll likely to find a framework supporting the several OSes you really care about (AFAIK, all of Boost, POCO, Qt know about Linux, Windows, MacOSX and offer a common API abstracting them; but you could find some academic operating system which is incompatible with them; in practice, any framework targeting both Windows and POSIX should be practically enough).

With some curiosity, you may find an OS with a good C++17 implementation which has a very weird API (look into [GNU Hurd](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/) for an example).

If your IPC facility is based on byte streams, look into [text-based protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) (perhaps [JSONRPC](https://www.jsonrpc.org/), SOAP, HTTP, ...). They are easier to code and most of them come with some C++ compatible library...

And with a few months of work and a lot of know how, you might even port a recent GCC or Clang to most other operating systems: they are careful to abstract the requirements on the OS in a clever way.

Remember, you could find OSes which don't even have any [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system): look into [CapROS](http://www.capros.org/) or [Contiki](http://www.contiki-os.org/) for some recent example, and look also inside [tunes.org](https://tunes.org/) where interesting discussions related to your topic, in the past century, have been archived. But with some pain (my guess is a few months of work for a GCC or Clang expert), you'll be able to port a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) to target it to obtain a C++17 cross-compiler targetting them.

IMHO, a C++ standard library which enables only to "open" one single "file" (supposedly named `THEFILE`) is conforming to the letter of the C++17 standard. AFAIK, you don't have any *guarantee* that `std::ifstream` or `std::ofstream` works successfully.

BTW, current processors are practically multi-core, so it makes a lot of sense to try running A and B in parallel and doing some IPC (in an OS specific way, perhaps abstracted by some framework or library).

Comment: I agree with @darune, it’s not sexy, but files work well.

Comment: If you are allowed to go through `std::system` - how could that look ? that might be an ok solution unless it is way too complicated.

Comment: @darune `std::system` isn't what you're after. It's "cheating", a way to ask the operating system to do something, but in a manner inferior to proper IPC tools. It doesn't meet your requirement of a purely C++ solution; in fact, it's quite the opposite :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah yea, i know, just curious

Comment: Couldn't you in theory use another file for handling the sync'ing ?

Comment: @darune - If you want to use files for syncing, you'd need something akin to `flock`, otherwise you're looking at a race waiting to happen.

Comment: @StephenNewell i know some others programs use a file as a lock (if it exists) - but probably this is only doable through the systems API.

Comment: @Basile Starynkeyvitch what about piping STDOUT of process A into STDIN of process B ?

Comment: Some operating systems don't have pipes.

Comment: Your recent edit of your question changed it completely. I still recommend using one of the frameworks I am mentioning